Embedding \input in \caption
I have some tex routines that were working great. And now, not. In particular, in the document I want 2 side by side images with captions. The captions need to be dynamic, with the content driven by an external file - captions won't always be the same or in the same order for each geography in question.
Here is the code that used to work (I apologize, but I can't figure out how to keep the code spacing/linebreaks):
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\linewidth}
\stepcounter{chart}
\renewcommand{\fignum}{\arabic{chart}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\graphdir}{{\input{\regiondir/ChartData/label\fignum\unskip}}}
\caption{\graphdir}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\regiondir/Charts/LQ_\fignum.png}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\linewidth}
\stepcounter{chart}
\renewcommand{\fignum}{\arabic{chart}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\graphdir}{{\input{\regiondir/ChartData/label\fignum\unskip}}}
\caption{\graphdir}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\regiondir/Charts/LQ_\fignum.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

And here is the error that I am getting:
[3]
(/Users/Jon/FileShare/Projects/HEC_Internal/QCEW/LQ/Reports/TeX/figureInput.tex
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   unskip 
l.8 \caption{\graphdir}
                       
?

I am completely flummoxed, so any thoughts would be much appreciated.
I am also open to a completely different algorithm/method.
Thank you in advance - Jon

For the correct formatting of code see: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your code with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. In your case the shown code should result in exactly the shown error message. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

It seems wrong to use \unskip in the argument of \input. IMHO you should remove it. But without a minimal (not working) example, this is only a guess.

it might have accidentally not given an error but using \unskip here \input{\regiondir/ChartData/label\fignum\unskip}  can never do anything useful, and an error would be expected. The argument has to expand to a filename, it hcan not have any typesetting commands such as font changes or spaces or unskips.

With \input{…\unskip} I get the same error message. After removing the \unskip something like:
\begin{filecontents*}{test-caption-a.tex}
This is a test caption for image a.
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
%  \caption{\protect\input{test-caption-a.tex\unskip}}% would fail with error
  \caption{\protect\input{test-caption-a.tex}}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

works.
Additional note: You are defining \graphdir robust and then you are using \graphdir as argument of \caption. If you'd have a look into the lof-file you will find the unexpanded \graphdir there for every such caption. So in the List of Figures always the same \graphdir would be used instead of a path depending on the chart counter. So using something like:
\begin{filecontents*}{test-example-caption-a.tex}
This is a test caption for image a.
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\newcounter{chart}
\renewcommand*{\thechart}{\alph{chart}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \stepcounter{chart}%
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{\protect\input{test-caption-\thechart.tex}}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

would be better, because here \thechart expands while writing to the aux file (and therefore would also be expanded in the lof file).

Another suggestion would be to write the whole \caption command to the external files. In this case, a simple \input would be enough:
\begin{filecontents*}{test-caption-a.tex}
\caption{This is a test caption for image a.}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test-caption-b.tex}
\caption{This is a test caption for image b.}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\newcounter{chart}
\renewcommand*{\thechart}{\alph{chart}}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \stepcounter{chart}%
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \input{test-caption-\thechart.tex}
  \label{fig:testA}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \stepcounter{chart}%
  \includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \input{test-caption-\thechart.tex}
  \label{fig:testB}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

